# Hide a character in text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change some text which says 'Name:' to 'Name'. In other words, I just want to hide the ':'.

Can jQuery select a character or word within a div? If so it would be easy to hide the ':' character or if needs be replace the text to same word but without that character.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use JQuery then ,

```
$('#idOfTheTextDIV').html($('#idOfTheTextDIV').html().replace("texttoHide",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

[javaScript replace() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Example code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Name:";
document.write(str.replace(/:/g, ""));

</script>
```

Comment: Probably a newbie question, but ive put the code before my closing head tag and the text 'Name' is being added to the top of the page, and the : is being left.

Comment: @jdln- first load whole page than replace the value of text by using innerhtml or innertext.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function replace.

```
var str = 'Name:';
str = str.replace(/:/g,'');
```

This will replace the ':' char with nothing basically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original question is whether jQuery can select based on the content of a node, not whether it can do a replace.  The answer is yes; you can select by content:

```
$("div:contains('Name:')");
```

Then, you can do a simple string replace on that node, assuming that you aren't going to have other instances on the page that also have "Name:" in which you don't want to remove the colon:

```
var $nameDiv = $("div:contains('Name:')")
$nameDiv.html($nameDiv.html().replace(/:/g,""); // Copied from others.  I didn't check this
```

I'm not sure how expensive the :contains() selector is - it sounds expensive.  So it might be better to wrap the key elements in a div with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code it's working fine.

```
function removeSelectedText () {
    if (window.getSelection || document.getSelection) {
        var oSelection = (window.getSelection ? window : document).getSelection();
        $('#text').text(
            $('#text').text().substr(0, oSelection.anchorOffset).replace( $('#text').text().substr(oSelection.focusOffset),''));
    } else {
        document.selection.clear();
    }
}

$('#remove').click(function() {
    removeSelectedText();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#gridscroll').html($('#gridscroll').html().replace("'",""));
```

'hi' >> hi'

```
$('#gridscroll').html($('#gridscroll').html().replace(/\'/g, ""));
```

'hi' >> hi