# Hide/remove piece of text

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I'm working with an XML file which is interpreted by Jquery and printed. Most items just have a `title` and `intro text` without any weird things.

There are just a few items that have a `title` and an `intro text` starting with some HTML. This HTML is not being interpreted as HTML, but as plain text

Example of intro text:
`<img src="url" alt="" title="" class="class" /> Intro text`
will be shown as `<img src="url" alt="" title="" class="class" /> Intro text`, which is wrong.
What I want is to just hide the whole `<img />` tag. Is that possible?

Yell if you need more information!
Thanks.

**More information**:

The XML offers it like this:
`&lt;img src=&quot;url&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; title=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;class&quot; /&gt; Intro Text` 
So it's logical that the output is `<img src="url" alt="" title="" class="class" /> Intro text`

Is it maybe possible to hide everything from < to >? (or from < to >)

**Update 2**:

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580287/hide-a-character-in-text-with-jquery) solution to hide a : from "Name:", that could maybe work with me as well, if there is something like a joker.
`var str = '<img *joker* />';
str = str.replace(/<img *joker* />/g,'');`
Or is that completely crazy?

Comment: Has $("your selector").hide() not worked?

Comment: I could try that with the class, which is probably the same for every image in that situation. I'll check it out!

Comment: It's possible to identify what image do you want to hide on your layout ?

Comment: Hi Ricardo: There is no image, it's just the HTML text you see there (I updated my question to explain how I get it delivered). If I can hide/remove everything from < to > would be fine.
@Thinking Sites: That doesn't work, because there is no class, as it's not interpreted as HTML. I get it delivered like &lt; and &quot; etc.

Comment: Oh, so you're not dealing with raw HTML, you're dealing with encoded HTML within an xml file, so you're really looking for a find and replace then. Yes?   If so, try using regular expressions to remove the data.  Would that work?

Comment: @Rvervuurt Can you give me an example of the initial string and the end string which you want ?

Comment: Initial string: `<img src="url" alt="" title="" class="class" /> Intro text`
End string: `Intro text`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parent tag it is quite easy :

```
<p id="yourid">
    <img src="url" alt="" title="" class="class" /> Intro text
</p>
```

The javascript is then :

```
$('#yourid').html($('#yourid').text());
```

(I replace the HTML content by the text content only).

Comment: I have updated my question, as I was not clear there is no HTML.