# How can I use jQuery/Javascript to hide elements that before anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, dom

So I'm currently working in Blackbaud/Convio CRM, and I have a question regarding using Javascript or jQuery to hide elements that are rendered onto the DOM, from the backend. Here is the code that is rendered from the backend, onto the DOM:

```
<div id="wrapperBlock">
<div class="topList">TOP COLORS</div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1025&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Orange</a>
    &nbsp;($100)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1022&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Black</a>
    &nbsp;($80)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1026&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Green</a>
    &nbsp;($75)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;4&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1024&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Yellow</a>
    &nbsp;($68)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;5&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1020&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Blue</a>
    &nbsp;($55)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;6&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1027&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Red</a>
    &nbsp;($43)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;7&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1021&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Purple</a>
    &nbsp;($30)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;8&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1023&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Pink</a>
    &nbsp;($47,546.81)
    <br />
</div>
```

The output onto the page looks something like this:

```
1 - Orange ($100)
2 - Black ($80)
3 - Green ($75)
4 - Yellow ($68)
5 - Blue ($55)
6 - Red ($43)
7 - Purple ($30)
8 - Pink ($20)
```

I want to hide the numbers, hyphens, and spaces that appear before each color. In addition, is it possible to hide the opening parenthesis and closing parenthesis that wrap each dollar amount?

To remove the '1 - ', I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#progress-companies').html().remove('&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;');
});
</script>
```

Can someone please give me a hint as to how to get rid of the numbers, dashes, and parentheses? Do I need regex?

EDIT/UPDATE:

Ooooh, I got somewhere using a line of code from @Sangeet-Menon's solution here [Hide a character in text with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580287/hide-a-character-in-text-with-jquery)

```
      $('#progress-companies').html($('#progress-companies').html().replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;",""));
});
```

Comment: @DavidThomas heh there's actually an 8 hidden in there

Comment: @Spokey: yeah, I just caught it. Thought it was a double ampersand at first glance... >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you want to keep only the `<a>` element, so far as I can tell, I'd suggest avoiding regular expressions<sup>**1**</sup> and simply:

```
// iterate over each of the '<a>' elements inside of the '#wrapperBlock':
$('#wrapperBlock a').each(function(){
  // caching the current node:
  var self = this;
  // removing the current node's previousSibling, the textNode
  // containing the characters you want to remove, from the parentNode:
  self.parentNode.removeChild(self.previousSibling);
  // removing the parentheses from the current node's nextSibling
  // (this is text, not HTML) using a regular expression and String.replace():
  self.nextSibling.nodeValue = self.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
});
```

```js
$('#wrapperBlock a').each(function(){
  var self = this;
  self.parentNode.removeChild(self.previousSibling);
  self.nextSibling.nodeValue = self.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperBlock">
  <div class="topList">TOP COLORS</div>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1025&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Orange</a>
  &nbsp;($100)
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1022&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Black</a>
  &nbsp;($80)
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1026&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Green</a>
  &nbsp;($75)
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;4&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1024&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Yellow</a>
  &nbsp;($68)
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;5&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1020&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Blue</a>
  &nbsp;($55)
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;6&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1027&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Red</a>
  &nbsp;($43)
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;7&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1021&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Purple</a>
  &nbsp;($30)
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;8&nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1023&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Pink</a>
  &nbsp;($47,546.81)
  <br />
</div>
```

---

1. Mainly because manipulating, and resetting, the HTML (using either jQuery's `html()`, or the native DOM's `innerHTML`) will unset any event-handlers assigned to the nodes inside of the HTML that you're manipulating, and will either need to be re-bound, or require delegated event-handling (using `on()`, for example).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
  - [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling).
  - [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).
  - [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling).
  - [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you! I also wanted the reformat the parentheses. Instead of Orange ($100), I wanted it to look like Orange - $100.

Comment: @techtolentino: may I ask if the answer now serves your needs?

Comment: yes this is great. Also, thanks for giving some resources for me to look into. I'm curious now, how to remove the dollar values too and show only the Color names, but I'll try investigating myself. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! Incidentally, to remove the `$` as well (though this begins to render the display of a price pointless), change the `self.nextSibling.nodeValue` line with the following: `self.nextSibling.nodeValue = self.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/\(\$|\)/g,'');`

Comment: this is great! I was able to just look at your code and use         `self.parentNode.removeChild(self.nextSibling);` to hide all dollar figures altogether. Then I commented out the last line that handled the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace()` for the rest of the numbers like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapperBlock').html(function (i, oldHTML){
        return oldHTML.replace(/&nbsp;&nbsp;[0-9]&nbsp;-&nbsp;/g, '');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperBlock">
<div class="topList">TOP COLORS</div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1025&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Orange</a>
    &nbsp;($100)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1022&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Black</a>
    &nbsp;($80)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1026&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Green</a>
    &nbsp;($75)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;4&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1024&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Yellow</a>
    &nbsp;($68)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;5&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1020&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Blue</a>
    &nbsp;($55)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;6&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1027&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Red</a>
    &nbsp;($43)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;7&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1021&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Purple</a>
    &nbsp;($30)
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;8&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a href="http://rcf.convio.net/site/TR?company_id=1023&amp;fr_id=1341&amp;pg=company">Pink</a>
    &nbsp;($47,546.81)
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using `html()` you can avoid `innerHTML` and make use of the arguments available to the anonymous function: `html(function (i, oldHTML) { return oldHTML.replace(/&nbsp;&nbsp;[0-9]&nbsp;-&nbsp;/g, ''); });`

Comment: Thanks, this looks great as well! I love the SO community!